# How to define a continuous 2D path?

Tags: general-topology

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)), $p: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ is a *path* in a topological space $X$ if $p$ is continuous. However, $p$ is a 1-dimensional path, i.e., it has no width. My question: How can a 2-dimensional topological path (i.e., with width) be defined? E.g., how can one define a path in $[0,1]^2$ that starts at $y=0$ and ends at $y=1$ but also has a width of $1$ (and thus covers the whole $[0,1]^2$ space)?

Comment: Maybe consider a path $p$ of no width, then do this: $\{u \in X : \operatorname{dist}(u,p) < \alpha\}$ for width $2\alpha$.  The original $p$ is the center line.  Of course $X$ has to be a metric space.

Comment: Note https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: To follow on copper.hat's comment, did you learn that space-filling curves exist and you're wondering how that can be, given that a path "has zero width"? (If so, the description of "width $1$" is not what's happening; more like "infinite length and crinkliness in a vary particular way.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with: $p: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a *2D path* in a topological space $X$ if:
$$
\forall x \le y \in [0,1]: p(x) \subseteq p(y)
$$
And:
$$
\forall x \in [0,1]: p(x) \text{ is a continuous plane}
$$
I.e., as the path progresses, it always contains the previous parts of the path. This is the *continuous* property.

E.g., the following *path* in $[0, 1]^2$ starts at $y=0$ and ends at $y=1$ but also has a width of 1 and thus covers the whole $[0,1]^2$ space:
$$
p(y) = \{(x, y'): 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y' \le y\} = [0,1] \times[0, y]
$$

Answer (score 0):

The domain of a path is always an interval ($1$-dimensional) by definition. The codomain is not limited to be $1$-dimensional though.

I don't know what you mean by the width of a path given in the standard definition. But I can imagine a path-like function $f:[0, 1] \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ defined by

$$
\forall t \in [0,1]:f(t) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~||x - (t,t)|| \le 1\}
$$

Then, $[0,1]^2 \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]}f(t)$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous here though? Honestly, I'm not sure how to define a continuous function in this 2D case.

Comment: @asherbar Neither am I... I was so naive. I think I have to do some research on that.